# Mounting Google Drive files in TermUX on Android

Tags: mount, backup, google-cloud, google-drive, google

I need to mount some Google Drive files in the TermUX client on my Realme 8 5G Android 12 device.

This is so that I may then copy and backup some of the files to Github (or, alternatively, it, in addition, to CStorage).

Is this at all possible?

When will it be supported?

Is anyone willing to implement it?

It would be very useful, to me, and I would really appreciate it.

If anything, even a client that downloaded the remote directory structure and asked me what I wanted to download, in terms of files to download.

Then, I can back it up, from the Unix Shell.

Thank you.